# Can java class run in nsis script?

Tags: java, nsis

I have installed NSIS plugin in My eclipse on windows platform.
I have java class Calculator.java

```
public class sample {

public static Integer sum(int a, int b) {
int c = a+b;
return c;
}

}
```

while installing, from sample.java class using method sum(5,6) i want to get this result in nsis file.

I need help in communication with nsis file to java. Is it possiable in nsis?. If its possible please give me the steps.

can any one help this concept?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You execute a Java JAR in NSIS with the ExecWait command.

```
ExecWait 'javaw.exe -jar \
            ${networkDir}\your.jar \
            parameters'
```

You can check the error flag if and only if your Java JAR returns a condition code:

```
System.exit(0);   // Good return
System.exit(8);   // Error return
```

As far as I know, you cannot reference Java methods in NSIS.  Your Java JAR must have a main method.

Your Java JAR can write a file which can be read later by NSIS.

Comment: @Gibert Thank you.I created setup.nsi successfully.where i execute this code? can you explain me?

Comment: @ILLA: You put the ExecWait where ever you want the Java code to execute in your setup script.  ExecWait is just another NSIS script command.

Comment: @Gibert I cant able to run this command in command line.Is there need to put in nsi script file?

Comment: @Gibert ExecWait 'javaw.exe -jar c:\LaptopAgent.jar start' put in script file.While i installing exe file it returns "A java exception occured".how to solve this?

Comment: @ILLA: Open up a Windows command window and type the javaw command into the window.  You should get an error telling you what the java exception is.

Comment: @Gibert If i put the same command in windows command got the same error("A java exception occured") only.

Comment: @ILLA: This is not a discussion board.  I can't walk you through your problem.  Feel free to post another Stack Overflow question showing what you've done.

Comment: @gibert sorry for in convince can u tell me is there need jar file? I dont know why are you used jar file command? I have java project only.